# How to give how many tries left

Tags: javascript

I have a homework problem in which I have to create a variable as a constant and store your password in this variable.

prompt the user for a password and let them know that they have 3 guesses to get the password correct.

if the password is correct let the user know and no further prompts should happen.

If the password is incorrect you should alert the user that the password is not correct and relay how many tries they have left.

After the 3rd guess, the user should be alerted that they are out of guesses and no more prompts should happen.

They only part I can't seem to figure out is how to say how many tries are left and then replay the message.

I have tried using the for loop but it gives `undefined`.

```js
const x = window.prompt("Enter a password")
var y = window.prompt("Reenter your password")
var i = 0
var message = []
message = " "

if (x === y) {
  window.alert("You got it right!")
} else {
  window.alert("Try again")
  for (i = 4; i < 4; i--) {
    message[0] += "You have " + i + "tries left"
    message[1] += "You have " + i + "tries left"
    message[2] += "You have " + i + "tries left"
    message[3] += "You are out of tries"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to put the prompt for the password inside the loop.

Comment: I tried that and all it gave me was try agian

Comment: First of all, an important thing is naming. Consider name your variables reflecting the content. Find variables names is like an art :) . Then, in your algo you have to find the same names that the ones you give in your explanation.

Comment: You've got some other issues too; you initialize `message` to an empty array (good), then immediately set it to a string (bad). But then it's not clear how the `message` array is going to be used...

Comment: I suggest you to restart from scratch, and you may start by listing all the variables at the beginning of your program. EnteredPassword, reenteredPassword, passwordEquals, tryCount, tryMax and so on. After that you write the story ;) once you have a story that work, you can say, how may I simplify it? Good cheers

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of completing others assignments, however, I hope that this might help you understand how JavaScript works.

First, you will need to move your `for`-loop to the top (below initializing `x` as the password) in order to have it about all of the code as you want to take all of the actions (show the prompts) each time:

```js
const x = window.prompt('Enter a password')
for (i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
  ...
}
```

Notice how I changed `i = 4` to `i = 3` as you want to have three tries and decrement in the last segment of the `for`-loop control because you want to go from `3` to `0`.

Now, you will also need to change the displaying part. You can just get rid of your `message` list as it should not be required:

```js
  ...
} else {
  if (i > 1) window.alert(`You have ${i} tries left.`)
  else window.alert(`You are out of tries.`)
}
```

I used an `if`-statement to determine whether there are still tries left. If `i == 1`, there are no tries left because that was the last try.
Also, I am using a **template literal** to display the amount of tries. [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

A possible solution *could* look like this:

```js
const x = window.prompt(`Enter a password`)
for (i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
  const y = window.prompt(`Reenter your password`)
  if (x === y) {
window.alert(`You got it right!`)
  } else {
if (i > 1) window.alert(`You have ${i} tries left.`)
else window.alert(`You are out of tries.`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that asks the user to re-enter their password needs to be in the loop.

You also have the loop conditions wrong. `i < 4` will never be true, because you initialize `i = 4`, so the loop ends immediately.

You set the variable `message`, but never use it for anything. There isn't really a need for 4 different variable settings, you can simply calculate the number of tries remaining by subtracting the current attempt from the limit.

```js
const x = window.prompt("Enter a password");
const maxtries = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < maxtries; i++) {
  var y = window.prompt("Reenter your password")
  if (x === y) {
    window.alert("You got it right!")
  } else {
    if (i < maxtries-1) {
      window.alert(`You have ${maxtries-1-i} tries left, try again`);
    } else {
      window.alert("You're out of tries");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// enter original password
const saved = window.prompt('Enter password: ');

// start loop for 3 attempts
for (let x = 2; x >= 0; x--) {
    // prompt for password attempt 
    const attempt = window.prompt('Reenter password: ');
    // produce failed attempt message
    const failed = (x > 0) ? x + ' tries left' : 'Failed to login...';
    // display success/failure message
    window.alert((attempt === saved) ? 'Success!' : failed);
    // exit loop if passwords match
    x = (attempt === saved) ? 0 : x;
}
```